# OpCode is being attached to event name in out-of-process Semantic logging (SALB) c#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, etw-eventsource, semantic-logging, slab

I am doing an out-of-process semantic logging with elastic search. When i browsed the events using kibana, i could see the events are coming. But the event name showing as "Event name + OpCode". That is events OpCode is being attached to the Event name.

One of my sample event is

```
Event(RequestStartId, Level = EventLevel.Verbose, Keywords = Keywords.Requests, Task = Tasks.Request, Opcode = EventOpcode.Start)]
public void RequestStart(string message)
{
    WriteEvent(message);
}
```

In elastic search(Kibana) the event name is showing as "**RequestStartStart**"

Is it normal behavior that the opcode is begin attached to event name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the built-in behavior of SLAB.  You can see it defined in the [`EventSchema`](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/semantic-logging/blob/master/source/Src/SemanticLogging/Schema/EventSchema.cs) class where the EventName is the TaskName concatenated with the OpcodeName:

```
public string EventName
{
    get { return this.TaskName + this.OpcodeName; }
}
```